# Catching Memory Exceptions in C Code From Ada

Tags: c, ada

I have some ada code that interfaces with some C functions, and I am having trouble catching memory exceptions/SIGSEGV signals in the ada code that are generated/raised by the C code.  I am using ada tasks which run the C functions, but the only way I know that there is a problem in the C code is that when I try to schedule more tasks, the ada code raises a `TASKING_ERROR`. This is okay, but it is impossible to figure out exactly where the problem came from, as the only indication of a problem is the `TASKING_ERROR` "all the way up" in my ada task scheduler.  Any ideas of a strategy that I might employ to pinpoint the actual cause of the tasking errors?

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try a last-chance exception handler in your task, compile with `-g`, and bind with `-bargs -E` (that is, if you're using `gnatmake`; otherwise, `gnatbind -E`).

With `segv.c` containing

```
void segv(void) {
  char *zero = 0;
  *zero = 0;
}
```

and

```
with Ada.Exceptions;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
procedure Call_Segv is
   task T;
   task body T is
      procedure Segv;
      pragma Import (C, Segv);
   begin
      Put_Line ("calling segv ...");
      Segv;
      Put_Line ("... done.");
   exception
      when E : others =>
         Put_Line ("... exception: "
                     & Ada.Exceptions.Exception_Information (E));
   end T;
begin
   null;
end Call_Segv;
```

building with

```
$ gnatmake call_segv.adb -g -bargs -E -largs segv.o -Wl,-no_pie
```

I get

```
$ call_segv
calling segv ...
... exception: Exception name: CONSTRAINT_ERROR
Message: erroneous memory access
Call stack traceback locations:
0x10002cea5 0x7fff8ff8a948 0x100002077 0x100002304 0x10000ef16 0x7fff8ff9c7a0
```

and the stack trace interprets as

```
$ atos -o call_segv 0x10002cea5 0x7fff8ff8a948 0x100002077 0x100002304 0x10000ef16 0x7fff8ff9c7a0
__gnat_error_handler (in call_segv) + 53
0x7fff8ff8a948
segv (in call_segv) (segv.c:3)
call_segv__tTKB.3158 (in call_segv) (call_segv.adb:10)
system__tasking__stages__task_wrapper (in call_segv) + 406
0x7fff8ff9c7a0
```

(that's on Mac OS X; on a more *normal* machine, you won't need the `-Wl,-no_pie` and you'll use `addr2line` instead of `atos`).

Comment: The above is exactly what I'm looking for.  I took your two units, compiled segv.c with `gcc -g -c segv.c`, then `gnatmake call_segv.adb -g -bargs -E -largs segv.o`, and got `calling segv... \n Execution terminated by unhandled exception \n Exception Name: STORAGE_ERROR \n Message: s-intman.adb:124 explicit raise \n Call stack traceback locations: 0xb7fc7cb9` which doesn't lead back to anything.  This is essentially the same problem I'm having with my larger application.  Perhaps something in my setup is wrong? I feel like I'm close to a solution at this point.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Which OS/compiler are you using? With Debian wheezy (GCC 4.6), I get a result very like the Mac one; that is, it successfully catches the exception in the task's exception handler, and I get a useful traceback, rather than your `Execution terminated by unhandled exception`. With Win XP and GNAT GPL 2012, I do get `Execution terminated ...` and no useful interpretation of the C part of the traceback, like you. Googling doesn't help (there was a comp.lang.ada thread, where someone reported problems like this with C).

Comment: Wow very interesting...we are using RHEL5.4, and `gcc -x Ada --version` returns 4.1.2.  I will try this later on a later version to see if I get better results.  Thanks again.

Comment: See also [*Gem #142 : Exception-ally*](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-142-exceptions).